# Why is this Python Regex Expression not working?

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regex expressions, and python. But created a script that uses multiple regex expressions. Two of which, work when run through Regexpal.com. But when I run the script. They do not work. Script works fine, when I run my other regex expressions. Here are the two that are not working. Can someone explain why they do not work, and give me the correct expressions?
I tested these three different ones, none work. I have a line with

```
Patient: Höler, Adam* 10.07.1920    ID-Nr: 1118111111
```

And I want to extract `Patient: Höler, Adam`.

```
Patient:\s.*\*
Patient:.*?([*])
Patient:.*\*
```

I have another line with

```
VCI-exsp = 20mm;
```

And I'm trying to extract `VCI-exsp=20mm` (get rid of the `';'`). This is the regex expression I made, but it also works on regexpal.com (and on Atom), but not when I run the script.

```
VCI-exsp =[^;]*
```

Here is the scripts I have, regexText is a text file full of my regex expressions. And Realthingnotaphony is the text file with the text I'm trying to extract data from. If the problem is that I'm not including r, how would I inject it into the expressions?

```
regexarr = []
with open("regexText.txt") as fw:
    for line in fw:
        regexarr.append(re.compile(line))
matchs = []
count = 1
with open('Realthingnotaphony.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for regexp in regexarr:
            test = re.search(regexp, line)
        if test != None:
            matchs.append(test)
            print(test.group(0))
```

Comment: You need to post your code. I'll bet anything you forgot to use a raw string for the regexp, so the backslashes aren't being passed through to the regexp processor.

Comment: Please create some Python code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: You say your script does not work, but you posted no script at all. How are we supposed to help?

Comment: You are reading lines from a file, and directly using them as regular expressions.  They will all end with a newline (except perhaps for the last line in the file), and therefore will try to match a newline at the end of the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading in from a text file but you are not stripping the newlines. This means your search criteria are not what you think they are. You can check this by using `print(regexarr)` after loading the first file.

```
[re.compile('Patient:\\s.*\\*\n'), re.compile('Patient:.*?([*])\n'), re.compile('Patient:.*\\*\n')]
```

Change your code to:

```
import re

with open("regexText.txt") as fw:
    # This removes the newline character
    regexarr = fw.read().splitlines()
# print(regexarr)
matchs = []
count = 1
with open('Realthingnotaphony.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for regexp in regexarr:
            test = re.search(regexp, line)
        if test != None:
            matchs.append(test)
            print(test.group(0))
```

Then your search terms `Patient:\s.*\*` and `VCI-exsp =[^;]*` will work.

*Note:*

You have a logic error in adding the entries to your match list because you are looping over each search term and resetting the result. This means you can only ever get a result on the last search term!

You can fix this by testing your output or by moving the regex loop. Note you can't just swap it with the `for line in f` because that is an iterator and you will exhaust the iterator on the first loop.

This would make your code:

```
import re

with open("regexText.txt") as fw:
    regexarr = fw.read().splitlines()
# print(regexarr)
matchs = []
count = 1
for regexp in regexarr:
    with open('Realthingnotaphony.txt') as f:
            for line in f:    
                test = re.search(regexp, line)
                if test != None:
                    matchs.append(test)
                    print(test.group(0))
```

You can also fix this by using the loading the entire file instead of each line and using the `re.findall` method rather than `re.search`. This will return a list of strings that you can then unbundle.